# Hibernate - why are there multiple repeated select statements in debug log?

Tags: hibernate, jsf, jpa, primefaces, entitymanager

Service method returns an object like this

```
return entityManager.find(Event.class, id);
```

inside of a @ViewScoped bean

The Event object has about 40 fields, some of which are mapped @ManyToMany.

When I use JavaScript to open a PrimeFaces dialog, Hibernate runs all the same queries it used to generate the initial page.  Whenever I do anything on the page that invokes the bean, Hibernate runs all the queries over again.  Not only that but the same SELECT query is repeated in the log dozens of times.  I have tried changing the FetchType from EAGER to LAZY and back again with no change.  I tried detaching my object from the persistence context but then my lazy Collections were not being loaded.  After a thorough Google search I was unable to find any related questions.  Furthermore, Hibernate is not actually throwing an exceptions, it is just running slowly because it is querying the database unnecessarily after the information has already been loaded into memory.

I am thinking there is something simple I have done incorrectly along the way and I was hoping the fine folks of StackOverflow may be able to point me in the right direction, anyone?

If I have not included enough information here, please ask me for any pertinent data that may be necessary to facilitate a solution.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing on the server-side that will cause hibernate to cache what it has retrieved. So every request to the server will result in hibernate retrieving the relevant objects. If you want to reduce this, you can employ a second level cache. Then retrievals by PK will be cached.

Keep in mind, a second-level cache when used in a cluster will require a clustered cache solution.

Comment: I only make one request to the server.  To call my EntityManger to find() the Object.  The Object returned by find() is populated in the bean which is used throughout the view.  I do not make any more calls to the database, so I am thinking there is some sort of Hibernate mechanism working behind the scenes that is alluding me.

Comment: So all of the multiple hibernate calls are happening within the same HTTP call to the server? In that case your session is not request scoped but as a smaller scope within some bean.

Comment: My session is ViewScoped, which means that after my initial call to find() to get the Object out of the database, Hibernate should not have to make any additional queries except to retrieve Lazy collections.

But even when I open a PrimeFaces dialog with JavaScript, Hibernate is making the same calls to the database as it did on the intial find().  I even tried putting the bean in SessionScope and this did not have any effect.